# how to submit multidimensional array form?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a form in which there are 4 types of sections (text, contact, portfolio, testimonial)
I have one button to add a new section (ADD SECTION). On click opens a pop to select section type(text, contact, portfolio, testimonial)
I don't know how can I handle the post request of this form

I have tried looping the sections array
but if I have two text type section and there is 5 total section then for text section its prints an error invalid offset.

```
if(isset($_FILES["content"]) || isset($_POST["content"])){
            $errors = 0 ;
            $this->load->library("form_validation");

            $this->form_validation->set_rules("title[]", "Title", "trim|callback_validate_input");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("tagline[]", "Tagline", "trim|callback_validate_input");
            for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST["section_type"]); $i++) {
                if($_POST["section_type"][$i] == "testimonial"){

                    $this->form_validation->set_rules("content[testi_name][]", "Testimonial Name", "trim");
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules("content[testi_heading][]", "Testimonial Heading", "trim");
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules("content[testi_content][]", "Testimonial", "trim");

                }else{
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules("content[]", "Text Content", "trim|callback_validate_input");
                }
            }
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("status[]", "Status", "trim|required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("section_type[]", "Section Type", "trim|required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("section_ids", "Sections IDs", "trim|required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("priority", "Priority", "trim|required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("user_id", "User ID", "trim|required|is_natural");


            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $errors = 1 ;
                $response["message"] .= validation_errors("<p class='text-danger'>", "<p><br>");
            }


            if(isset($_FILES["content"])){

                $allowed_types       = array("image/png", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/jpeg");
                $max_size            = 153600;

                if(isset($_FILES["content"]["name"]["portfolio"])){
                    //validate portfolio images
                    $portfolio_path   = "./assets/images/portfolio/";
                    for($b = 0; $b < count($_FILES["content"]["name"]["portfolio"]); $b++){
                        $file_name = $_FILES["content"]["name"]["portfolio"][$b];
                        $type = $_FILES["content"]["type"]["portfolio"][$b];
                        $tmp = $_FILES["content"]["tmp_name"]["portfolio"][$b];
                        $size = $_FILES["content"]["size"]["portfolio"][$b];

                        if(!empty($file_name)){
                            if(!in_array($type, $allowed_types)){
                                $errors = 1 ;
                                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'> ".$file_name ." is not a valid image for portfolio.<p><br>"; 

                            }else if($size > $max_size){
                                $errors = 1 ;
                                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'> ".$file_name ."  is lager than allowed upload size(150 kb).<p><br>";
                            }else if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $portfolio_path."$file_name")){
                                $errors = 1 ;
                                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'> ".$file_name ."  could not be uploaded.<p><br>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_FILES["content"]["name"]["testi_img"])){
                    //validate testimonial images
                    $portfolio_path   = "./assets/images/testimonial/";
                    for($a = 0; $a < count($_FILES["content"]["name"]["testi_img"]); $a++){
                        $file_name = $_FILES["content"]["name"]["testi_img"][$a];
                        $type = $_FILES["content"]["type"]["testi_img"][$a];
                        $tmp = $_FILES["content"]["tmp_name"]["testi_img"][$a];
                        $size = $_FILES["content"]["size"]["testi_img"][$a];

                        if(!empty($file_name)){
                            if(!in_array($type, $allowed_types)){
                                $errors = 1 ;
                                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'> ".$file_name ." is not a valid image for testimonial.<p><br>"; 

                            }else if($size > $max_size){
                                $errors = 1 ;
                                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'> ".$file_name ."  is lager than allowed upload size(150 kb).<p><br>";
                            }else if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $portfolio_path."$file_name")){
                                $errors = 1 ;
                                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'> ".$file_name ."  could not be uploaded.<p><br>";
                            }
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }


            if($errors === 0){

                $section_ids = explode(",", $_POST["section_ids"]);
                //update / add new sections
                $this->load->model("sections_model");
                $output = array();
                for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST["section_type"]); $i++) {

                    $user_id = $_POST["user_id"] ;
                    $section_id = $section_ids[$i];
                    $priority = $i;
                    $title = $_POST["title"][$i] ;
                    $tagline = $_POST["tagline"][$i] ;
                    $status = $_POST["status"][$i] ;
                    $section_type = $_POST["section_type"][$i] ;

                    $section = array(
                        "section_id" => $section_id,
                        "user_id" => $user_id,
                        "section_name" => $title,
                        "section_tagline" => $tagline,
                        "section_priority" => $priority,
                        "section_type" => $section_type,
                        "status" => $status,
                    );

                    if($section_type == "portfolio"){
                        foreach ($_FILES["content"]["name"]["portfolio"] as $portfolio) {
                            $section["section_content"][] = $portfolio ;
                        }
                    }else if($section_type == "testimonial"){
                        $count = 0 ;
                        foreach ($_FILES["content"]["name"]["testi_img"] as $testi_image) {
                            $section["section_content"][$count] = array(
                                "image" => $testi_image,
                                "name" => $_POST["content"]["testi_name"][$count],
                                "heading" => $_POST["content"]["testi_heading"][$count],
                                "content" => $_POST["content"]["testi_content"][$count]
                            );
                        $count++;
                        }
                    }else {
                        $section["section_content"] = $_POST["content"][$i];
                    }


                    $check_section = $this->sections_model->select_all(array(
                        "where" => array(
                            "section_id" => $section_id,
                            "user_id" => $user_id
                        )
                    ));
                    $output[$i] = $section;
                    // if($check_section->num_rows()>0){
                    //  //update query
                    //  if($this->sections_model->update_row(array(
                    //      "section_id" => $section_id,
                    //      "user_id" => $user_id
                    //  ), $section)){
                    //      $response["message"] = "<p class='text-success'>Section Updated Successfully.</p>";
                    //  }else{
                    //      $response["message"] = "<p class='text-danger'>Unknown Error! Try Again Later.</p>";
                    //  }
                    // }else{
                    //  //insert query
                    //  if($this->sections_model->insert_row($section)){
                    //      $response["message"] = "<p class='text-success'>Section Added Successfully.</p>";
                    //  }else{
                    //      $response["message"] = "<p class='text-danger'>Unknown Error! Try Again Later.</p>";
                    //  }
                    // }

                }

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($output);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }else{
                $response["message"] .= "<p class='text-danger'>direct script not allowed</p><br>";
        }
```

> // this is what I got in return
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 3
>
> Filename: admin/Users.php
>
> Line Number: 642
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   E:\VIKASH\xampp\htdocs\zrurt\application\controllers\admin\Users.php
>   Line: 642 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: E:\VIKASH\xampp\htdocs\zrurt\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 4
>
> Filename: admin/Users.php
>
> Line Number: 642
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   E:\VIKASH\xampp\htdocs\zrurt\application\controllers\admin\Users.php
>   Line: 642 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: E:\VIKASH\xampp\htdocs\zrurt\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 18
            [user_id] => 31
            [section_name] => portfolio
            [section_tagline] => portfolio tagline
            [section_priority] => 0
            [section_type] => portfolio
            [status] => active
            [section_content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => user6.png
                    [1] => user7.png
                    [2] => user8.png
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 19
            [user_id] => 31
            [section_name] => testimoinial
            [section_tagline] => testimonial tagline
            [section_priority] => 1
            [section_type] => testimonial
            [status] => active
            [section_content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => user1.png
                            [name] => user 1
                            [heading] => heading one
                            [content] => testimonial one.
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => user2.PNG
                            [name] => user 2
                            [heading] => user two
                            [content] => testimonial two.
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 20
            [user_id] => 31
            [section_name] => about us
            [section_tagline] => about tagline
            [section_priority] => 2
            [section_type] => text
            [status] => active
            [section_content] => contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section. contact section.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 21
            [user_id] => 31
            [section_name] => contact us
            [section_tagline] => contact tagline
            [section_priority] => 3
            [section_type] => text
            [status] => active
            [section_content] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 22
            [user_id] => 31
            [section_name] => contact us
            [section_tagline] => contact tagline
            [section_priority] => 4
            [section_type] => contact
            [status] => active
            [section_content] => 
        )

)
```

I want to validate all fields and save them to the database.

Comment: Can you post what is in line 642

Comment: $section["section_content"] = $_POST["content"][$i];

Comment: I see `$_POST["content"]` have key-value pairs. Not index numbers `[$i]`. That's why you are getting this error. If you use like `["content"]["name"]` it will work.

Comment: You are using `count($_POST["section_type"])` to determine how far your `for` loop needs to run, but then what you are actually accessing is `$_POST["content"]` - that doesn’t match up …

Comment: $_POST["content"] have both key value pair and index nubers @HasithaMJayawardana

Comment: $_POST["section_type"] and $_POST["content"] both have equal count so i don't think it is the issue @04FS

Comment: Have you verified that, or are you just assuming? If you have not done so already, make a debug output of what you are actually receiving first of all, `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: yes  i do have checked . @04FS

Comment: Can you show the result of `var_dump($_POST);` then, please?

Comment: last section of code, after the errors is the output of $_POST["content"] @04fs

Comment: Still doesn’t allow us to verify what $_POST["section_type"] contains.

Comment: [section_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => text
            [2] => portfolio
            [3] => testimonial
            [4] => contact
        )
is the output of print_r($_POST["section_type"]);
@04FS